# Remove span tag from element html dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have code like this, and it's fetching data from other website.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("www.example.com");
    
$info['diesel']   = $html->find(".on .price",0)->innertext;
$info['pb95']   = $html->find(".pb .price",0)->innertext;
$info['lpg']   = $html->find(".lpg .price",0)->innertext;
```

The html code from other website looks:

```
<a href="#" class="station-detail-wrapper on text-center active">
   <h3 class="fuel-header">ON</h3>
   <div class="price">
      5,97
      <span>zł</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

So if i use `echo $info['diesel']` it shows me **5,97 zł**. I would like to delete this `<span>zł</span>` to show price only.

Comment: What does `$html->find(".on .price",0)->plaintext;` return?

Comment: @Bossman the documentation for the library in use here is [freely available](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom_node/innertext/)

Comment: @esqew yes, but `->plaintext` will return the string `5,97zł` without the span tags, then you could format it. Just another angle of attack..

Comment: @Bossman Yes, you’re correct-read your comment a bit too quickly before my first coffee of the day, unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can replace that span tag with blank:

```
echo $info['diesel']=str_replace("<span>zł</span>","",$info['diesel']);
```